# Can I get Tourist Visa for London?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, london, tourist-visas

I'm an Indian citizen having C1/D US visa working on ship.

Is it possible to get tourist visa and stay for 2 days in London since I will be transiting via London?

Comment: Does it need to be 2 days? You'd qualify for [UK transit without visa](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-to-transit-landside/) for up to 24 hours on the basis of your onward US visa, which would be much simpler than applying for a UK visa....

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to get a tourist visa for the UK if you meet the criteria.

You can look at the UK Home Office website about [visitor visa](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/) and [transit visa](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/transit/visa/) since you will need one or the other to enter the UK.

The status of C1/D visa from the US doesn't aware you an special status in receiving UK tourist visa, you do, however, qualify for [transit without concession](http://ukimmigrationspecialist.com/2012/02/12/transit-transit-without-visa-concession/) with a valid US visa but it only refers for air arrival and departure.

So is it possible: Yes.  Will you have any preferential treatment because you hold a US visa: Nope.

Comment: It's a valid US visa though, so wouldn't the OP be covered by that? ([Official Border Agency site](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-to-transit-landside/) lists just needing a valid US visa, as does the page you linked to much further down)

Comment: @Gagravarr Need more sleep cause I don't see things.  I'll correct the answer, but the way the question reads it suggests arrival by boat.

Comment: I thought it was someone heading to the US from India via London, en-route to work on a boat, who fancied a few days in London rather than just 2 hours in the airport changing planes, BICBW...

Comment: This is a C1/D visa which is not a US work visa but a US transit visa for people working on a ship